# Getting exact HTML of an xpath from selenium python driver

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

Basically I am an trying to get the html table of a page to save in database. Where I am getting the element by:

`data = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table[2]')`

**Here is the HTML that I am looking for:**

```
<table class="general" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="3" border="0" width="550">
  <tbody>
  <tr class="generaltitle">
    <td colspan="3">I am a basic title</td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top"><td colspan="3"><hr></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

But when I call this it gives me a raw result likt this:

```
"I am a basic title\n  \n\n  "
<br>
<hr>
```

I am calling it like this: `data.get_attribute('innerHTML')`

**How to get the exact HTML?**

Comment: @Grasshopper, I'm quite sure that you are wrong and `get_attribute('innerHTML')` should work exactly as OP expect

Comment: I second @Andersson, it should work. What webdriver are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you were looking for `data.get_attribute('outerHTML')`